# Difference between using provide() and assigning a variable for page titles in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, yield

Could someone explain why it is preferred when embedding ruby for things like page titles to use

```
<% provide(:title, 'Help') %>
```

and then using

```
<%= yield :title %>
```

rather than jus using a variable:

```
<% title = 'Help' %>
<%= title %>
```

I'm assuming its to do with the fact that you can `yield` *before* you have called `provide()` but if that is the case why is it not possible to call the variable *before* defining it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simply render a variable in the view, the second method will do.

However, `provide` and `yield` offer a various ways to build the rendered content. For, example, you pass instance variable like `@posts` which you may already assign a variable after a complicated algorithm, which you will not do in a view template.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: Thank you the second link was very helpful, so content_for is just seperating off a seperate chunk of code that can be rendered via yield(:foo) in addition to the regular yield for the view in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

`provide` (or `content_for`) are used to pass some elements from the view to the layout, so if you have layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield :title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Than in all the views, you can set the content for title with `provide` or content for. Local variables cannot do this, as they only live in a given view.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use an instance variable to overcome the scope restrictions of a local variable that you describe?

Answer (score 1):

provide stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. In this case, 'Help' in the symbol `:title`. The provide is enclosed in `<% %>` to indicate it is executing this code and not printing out in the view.

`yield` in this case just spits that block back out. The yield is enclosed in `<%= %>` to indicate it is being printed out into the view.

Think of it as setting a variable and printing out a variable.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide for more information. Note that `provide` is really a wrapper for `content_for` so that's where the good stuff is in that link.